# Enable Editing Excel sheet through Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Am trying to execute a automation test script, where the user downloads a excel sheet from the site and opens the same downloaded excel sheet for writing data into the excel sheet, but the excel sheet is not edited since it opens in protected mode. I need solution for how can i remove the protected mode.

Comment: and you think this can be solved with selenium? I highly doubt it.

Comment: @luksch well am a fresher, I tried to record the shortcut keys to remove the excel sheet from protected mode. But I guess selenium webdriver doesn't have control outside the browser ?                      Can we SaveAs the downloaded excel sheet in selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need some tool outside "simple" browser automation. Maybe [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/) or [macromonkey](http://www.macromonkey.com/) can help you with this, if you are under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot edit an Excel file using Selenium!**

Selenium is a browser automation tool, it can only interact with HTML (or XML) pages displayed in the browser.

If you want to interact with something like an excel file you would first need to download it and then programatically interact with it via code.

To download files have a look at this blog entry:

- http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/

When you have downloaded the file you will then need to programatically load it up so that you can query it, for this have a look at libraries like:

- http://poi.apache.org/
- http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/
- http://jxls.sourceforge.net/

One possible example is available here:

- https://github.com/Ardesco/Ebselen/blob/master/ebselen-core/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/ebselen/customhandlers/ExcelHandler.java